# HTML CSS strange gaps between divs

Tags: html, css

Please see the below code and screenshot.  Can anyone please explain why there are white gaps between the divs and how to remove them? I would like the divs sit next to one another without any margin between them

```html
![
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #b3b3b3;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }

        #containerdiv {
            width: 1184px;
            height: 626px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: -338px;
            margin-left: -552px;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
        }

        #centerdiv {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1024px;
            height: 576px;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        #lowercenterdiv {
            background-color: #ff00ff;
            width: 1024px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #lowerleftdiv {
            background-color: #00ff00;
            width: 80px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #leftdiv {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #ff000f;
            width: 80px;
            height: 576px;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 576px;
        }

        #rightdiv {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #000fff;
            width: 80px;
            height: 576px;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 576px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        #lowerrightdiv {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #fff000;
            width: 80px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: right;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 50px;
        }

        .arrowimg img {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="containerdiv">
        <div id="leftdiv"><img class="arrowimg" src="leftarrow.png"></div>
        <div id="centerdiv">

        </div>
        <div id="rightdiv"><img class="arrowimg" src="rightarrow.png"></div>
        <div id="lowerleftdiv">?</div>
        <div id="lowercenterdiv">?</div>
        <div id="lowerrightdiv">?</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Using `display: inline-block` creates spaces because of indentation (which is interpreted as one space). Try to use `float: left;` and see if that solved your problem. I can imagine the bottom space comes about because of line-height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to remove all your `position: absolute`s, as they make things complicated. What you want is: three boxes next to each other, then three boxes next to each other below it. If you float them to the left, you solve this problem. I have amended your CSS, just copy and paste and you can see the gaps disappear because floating elements don't care about whitespaces. There are other difficulties involved with floating, but it does solve your problem.

I have also removed everything I didn't need to get my point across.

```
#containerdiv {
    width: 1184px;
    height: 626px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-338px;
    margin-left:-552px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

// I added this to float all the divs inside your container to float
#containerdiv div {
    float: left;
}

#centerdiv {
    // I removed position: absolute from every box, as well as line-heights, align and display
    width: 1024px;
    height: 576px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#lowercenterdiv {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
} 

#lowerleftdiv {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
} 

#leftdiv {
    background-color: #ff000f;
    width: 80px;
    height: 576px;
} 

#rightdiv {
    background-color: #000fff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 576px;
} 

#lowerrightdiv {
    background-color: #fff000;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction.  It was actually the line breaks (whitespace) in the HTML that was causing the problem.  Floating the elements solves the problem because floating is less affected by whitespace, while inline-block seems to have problems.  I fixed this by removing the line breaks in the markup, so all of the divs were on the same editor line.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: If not alerted, divs have no margin or padding by default in any browser.

Comment: @somethinghere there are probably some browsers that have, but the common ones don't

Comment: @msrd0 Yeah, all might have been _too_ catch all :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird thing in how html is interpreted. The whitespace between the divs is rendered as a space. There are many ways to solve this, and none of them are very pretty.

One way is like this:

```
<div id="leftdiv">
    <img class="arrowimg" src="leftarrow.png">
</div>
<div id="centerdiv">
</div>
<div id="rightdiv">
    <img class="arrowimg" src="rightarrow.png">
</div>
<div id="lowerleftdiv">
    ?
</div>
<div id="lowercenterdiv">
    ?
</div>
<div id="lowerrightdiv">
    ?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope its fix

```css
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-sizing: border-box;
}
```